# How to get facebook dialog within same screen (popover)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, popover

On my website I'm using the Facebook SDK to open a send-dialog (as [described here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog)) with the following code:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'send',
  link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/04/15/travel/europe-favorite-streets.html',
});
```

This works fine, except for the fact that it opens in a pop-up which is blocked by my browser. On another website I saw that they open the dialog in some sort of pop-over (see image below).

Does anybody know how I can open the FB send-dialog in a pop-over like in the image below? All tips are welcome!

[image]

Comment: This should happen automatically, if the user is logged in to Facebook already. (If it doesn’t, try specifying the `display` parameter as `iframe` explicitly, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog#params)

Comment: @CBroe - Ah, I clearly didn't read the (f) manual well enough. Turns out that the reason is that people don't log into my app using the FB sdk, but using a server side self-implemented OAuth implementation. I tried using the `display: iframe` you suggested, but that doesn't work. Any idea how I could use it in an iframe despite the fact that the users are not logged in using the FB SDK?

Comment: They need to login to Facebook before they can use the dialog, and FB login can not be done in any kind of frame or iframe, for security reasons.

Comment: The docs say "If you are using the Facebook SDK for JavaScript, this will default to a modal iframe type for people logged into your app or async when using within a game on Facebook.com, and a popup window for everyone else." Displaying the pop-up seems default behaviour and cannot be changed.

Comment: @Bangdel - I indeed read that as well. I guess I now need to reimplement the login so that it uses the Facebook SDK. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it doesn't work in a pop-over because I don't use the FB-SDK for a login (I implemented the FB-login through my server). So I just need to reimplement my login so that it uses the Facebook-SDK for logging in.

Thanks for all the suggestions!